How to change drive configuration for webcam?
I'm using an external webcam, and it used to work well but suddenly stopped, only showing a black screen. From my sudo lshw, the problem seems to be it is only recognized as an "audio" device.

*-usb:1
description: Video
product: Lenovo FHD Webcam Audio
vendor: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
physical id: 4
bus info: usb@1:4
version: 50.02
serial: SN0001
capabilities: usb-2.00
configuration: driver=snd-usb-audio maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s

I see my laptop webcam which is working is configured as video as follows.

*-usb:3
description: Video
product: LG Camera
vendor: EBP63421702810011281
physical id: 6
bus info: usb@1:6
version: 0.11
serial: 200901010001
capabilities: usb-2.00
configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s

Is there a way to change the driver manually? Since it has worked well, I'm so confused.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, and yes, I've tried unplugging the camera and rebooting the computer multiple times but it still doesn't work.

I have two previous kernels, so tried both of them, but still have the same issue. Thank you for the suggestion, though!

Please edit your question and add this information. This will help others trying to solve the problem.
